# MySQLi printing out database with whileloop

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop

I am trying to take data from a table called posts in my database. 
The problem is that it says "Cannot connect to Database" and I can't seem to fiqure out why.
The connection credentials are correct and the database is there.
The following code is for the profile page of my website.

```
<div class="profilePosts">
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'trentfind');
     if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->connect_errno} : {$mysqli->connect_error}</p>";
    exit();
}

    $getposts = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_posted_to = 'username' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10") or die(mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getposts)) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $body = $row['body'];
        $date_added = $row['date_added'];
        $added_by = $row['added_by'];
        $user_posted_to = $row['user_posted_to'];
        echo "<div class='posted_by'><a href='$added_by'>$added_by</a> - $date_added - </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;$body<br /><hr />";
    }
?>
```

Comment: We can't really help you with this with such a low amount of information. What kind of environment do you work in? Is the database actually there? Are the credentials right? etc etc.

Comment: are you sure about the name of the database, root must be access to all the databases.

Comment: wrong passsword / wrong database name / database is down

Comment: I edited the post, and everything is up and the credentials are correct @Jordy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution to my problem. I just had to change around the jQuery to a way that made more sense

```
    $getposts = "SELECT id, body, date_added, added_by, user_posted_to FROM posts WHERE     user_posted_to = '$username'";

    $newQuery = mysqli_query($myConnection, $getposts) or die(mysql_error());
```

Thanks for the replys

Comment: You're mixing APIs with `mysql_error()` that needs to be `mysqli_error($myConnection)`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would suggest checking the MySql log for the host system.

Also, I would not recommend connecting to it from PHP as 'root'. Bear in mind the details you need to connect to the database are not the same that you use to log in to the host.

Comment: This honestly looks like a development area where he is working in. Something like WAMP.